# Is there any way to reset the tunnel in iOS using NE Packet Tunnel Provider when switch between wifi and mobile data happens?

Tags: ios, tunnel, apple-developer, networkextension, packet-loss

I’m working on an iOS App, where I’ve added NE Packet Tunnel Provider and using Network Path Monitor to detect when any switch between Wifi and Mobile Data is happening. If any switch in Network path is detected then canceling the Tunnel and restarting it again, in between the process  few packets are being dropped. I wanted to know if anyone knows if it’s possible without canceling and restarting the tunnel, can we reset the process so that it works seamlessly.